# UWP publish output always in test folder

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.forms, uwp, visual-studio-app-center

Why is it that even though I have the build setting in Visual Studio set to `Release` everything I create within a side-loaded UWP distribution is placed within a folder with `_test` on the end? Is it because MS assumes a side-loaded app is always a test app?

I place my appxbundle files within AppCenter and I'm using AppCenter to distrubute our internal production apps to our internal employess using AppCenter.

[image]

Here is the main reason I'm even asking.  I have tried to publish an appxbundle to the AppCenter for my employees to download and install.  Problem is, these target laptops don't have the Microsoft Store installed (don't ask) so the appxbundle won't auto-install.  So, when I try to install via a powershell script I can clearly see that the dependency for `Microsoft.NET.Native.Runtime.2.0` isn't being met and the install fails.  When I extract the appxbundle for my app I see no dependencies are included.  But, if I explore the root folder that my app is published to, I can find the `Microsoft.NET.Native.Runtime.2.0` is there, it's just not making it into the appxbundle file.  In order to install this app on these laptops I have to enable developer mode, I have to zip up the entire published folder, send this zip file to the user, have them extract it, then have them run the powershell script within the root folder.  This powershell script installs my appxbundle, cert, and includes all dependencies.

I read [HERE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/build/windows/uwp/results) the following:

> App Center always generates an app bundle. However, Debug builds are
>   not meant to be used for sideloading. ...and the provided .appxbundle
>   files in the Test folder do not contain required dependencies.

Since my dependencies are not included within the appxbundle and based on what Microsoft said, it appears my app is being generated as a `Debug` build even though I'm selecting `Release` within my IDE before publishing.

Comment: Does this have an impact on your business?

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT I better clarified why I'm asking the question

Comment: Have you selected **Always**  in the Generate app bundle listbox?

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT yes it's set to Always.

Comment: The build log does say it's building for `Release` so I guess all this is by design, it's just confusing.

Comment: As you said, it is by design, less documents explaining this.

Comment: What? This doesn't make any sense. Appending `_Test` for no reason? @PostImpatica, you should probably just open a bug in VS through the Feedback option - I also do not like magic misleading strings

Answer (score 2):

Sadly it's hard-coded in the msbuild file "Microsoft.AppxPackage.Targets"

Location for VS2019 `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v16.0\AppxPackage\Microsoft.AppxPackage.Targets`

[image]

---

Or as [MSFT UWP Engineer Nico Zhu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7254781/nico-zhu-msft) said in the comments: "it is by design"

---

See also: [Customizing Visual Studio MSIX packaging project output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63508078/customizing-visual-studio-msix-packaging-project-output)

Comment: Yet another ingenious decision of the UWP Engineers

Comment: It's also the same for Win UI 3 projects

Answer (score 1):

For anyone coming in the future, the proper way to remove the `_Test` suffix in the package name is by adding this to your `.csproj` file. It should be inside the `<Project>` tag

```xml
  <Target Name="SetAppxPackageTestDir" BeforeTargets="_ComputeAppxPackageOutput">
    <PropertyGroup>
      <AppxPackageNameNeutral>$(ProjectName)_$(AppxManifestIdentityVersion)</AppxPackageNameNeutral>
      <_AppxPackageConfiguration Condition="'$(Configuration)' != 'Release'">_$(Configuration)</_AppxPackageConfiguration>
      <AppxPackageName>$(AppxPackageNameNeutral)_$(Platform)$(_AppxPackageConfiguration)</AppxPackageName>
      <AppxPackageTestDir>$(AppxPackageDir)$(AppxPackageNameNeutral)$(_AppxPackageConfiguration)\</AppxPackageTestDir>
      <AppxPackageTestExternalPackagesDir>$(AppxPackageDir)$(AppxPackageNameNeutral)$(_AppxPackageConfiguration)\$(ExternalPackagesDir)</AppxPackageTestExternalPackagesDir>
    </PropertyGroup>
  </Target>
```

This will override the variables being set by visual studio and has the added benefit of only affecting the current project