# Why does VS 2019 append "_Test" to the folder name when I create .msix packages

Tags: msix

I am creating an .msix package from VS 2019. The application being packaged is a .NET Core 3.1 WFP desktop app.

The package (.msixbundle) executes correctly and is named correctly.

However, the folder that the package is placed always has a "_Test" appended (suffix) to the end of the folder it is located in. If I publish the package to a web server or file share there will be an accumulation of folders ending in "_Test". This occurs regardless of whether I'm creating a debug or release version.

I have search the Solution for the word Test but it's not there. I've created simple generic apps and the "_Test" suffix is always present on the folder names of the packages.

Where does this come from?

Comment: Duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63508078/customizing-visual-studio-msix-packaging-project-output/63700931#63700931

Comment: @Bogdan has a solution for you, but to answer the question "why?" --  VS assumes that you want to ship your final product through the Microsoft Store, so if you build packages **not** for the Store they "must" be for testing. This was originally true in Windows 8, but now you can also sideload them by default.

Comment: Not surprised. But really!

Answer (score 0):

Usually msix package append this kind of suffix due you are publishing in debug mode.

```
dotnet publish --framework:net7.0-windows10.0.19041.0 --configuration:debug
```

Publish as release and it disappear.

```
dotnet publish --framework:net7.0-windows10.0.19041.0 --configuration:release
```